# GPIO control with AJAX and Django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, raspberry-pi, gpio

So I encountered a problem I can't solve even having searched stack's resources and google. Let me share it with you.

My config/tools are Raspberry Pi Zero W, Raspbian, python 3.5, Django framework, Bootstrap.

I am communicating through and control GPIO on RPi via web browser (Chrome).

My testbench is a set of LEDs which I am able to switch on and off using shell as well as using a straight-forward MVC (the circuit is correct).

My goal and problem at the same time is to switch on and off the LEDs using AJAX so the page does not reload each time a button is pressed (what happens when I do not employ jquery/AJAX).

At current stage after pressing a button it seems all the code is executed except of the function *control_button* in **views.py**.

My logs after clicking a button:

```
"GET /vendapp/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6027
"POST /vendapp/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6027
```

AJAX also gets to execute **success: function...**

Here is the code:

**html 1**

```
<!doctype html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../../../favicon.ico">

    <title>FP</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'personal/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" type = "text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'personal/css/custom1.css' %}" type = "text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'personal/css/conti1.css' %}" type = "text/css"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <style type="text/css">
        html,
        body {
          height:100%
        }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="container-fluid p-0 px-md-0 mb-0">
        <div class="d-flex flex-row flex-md-row align-items-center p-0 px-md-0 mb-0 border-bottom box-shadow">  
            <div class="col">
                <div class="media align-items-center p-2 px-md-0 mb-0">
                    <img class="mb-1" src="{% static '/personal/img/c.png' %}" class="responsive-img" style='max-height: 64px; max-width: 64px;' alt="c1">
                    <div class="media-body">
                    <h5 class="mt-0">TITLE</h5>
                    <h6><em>Cliche</em></h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </header>

    <main>
      {% block content %}
      {% endblock %}
    </main>

    <footer>
      ...
    </footer>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="{% static 'personal/jquery/jquery.js' %}"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>   
    <script src="{% static 'personal/js/bootstrap.js' %}"></script>
    {% block javascript %}{% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

**html 2**

```
{% extends "personal/header3.html" %}

{% block javascript %}

<script>

$(function() {

    function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
    }
    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

    function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
        return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
    }

    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            }
        }
    });

    $('.btn-outline-primary').click(function(){
            var pinID = $(this).attr('data-pinID');
            alert(pinID);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{% url 'control_button' %}",
            data: {'getdata': JSON.stringify(pinID)},
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function(){
                alert(pinID);
                console.log(pinID);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('error');
            }
        });

    });

});
</script>

{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{% load static %}

<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="container-fluid p-0 px-md-0 mb-0 " id="main">


    <div class="d-flex flex-row flex-md-row align-items-center p-0 px-md-0 mb-0">
        <div class="col-sm-8">

            <div class="container-fluid">

                    <button type="button" id="btn4" data-pinID="127" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary border-0 mt-4 mr-3 ml-3 mb-3 pt-4 pl-3 pr-3 pb-3" style="background: url({% static '/personal/img/blk.jpg'%}) center">
                    </button>   

                    <button type="button" id="btn5" data-pinID="191" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary border-0 mt-4 mr-3 ml-3 mb-3 pt-4 pl-3 pr-3 pb-3" style="background: url({% static '/personal/img/blk.jpg'%}) center">
                    </button>

                    <button type="button" id="btn6" data-pinID="223" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary border-0 mt-4 mr-3 ml-3 mb-3 pt-4 pl-3 pr-3 pb-3" style="background: url({% static '/personal/img/blk.jpg'%}) center">
                    </button>                               
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    </div>  

</div>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from time import sleep
from smbus2 import SMBusWrapper
import json, sys
from django.http import JsonResponse, HttpResponse

DURATION = 4.0

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'personal/home.html')

def control_button(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        btn_pin = int(request.POST.get('getdata', None))
        with SMBusWrapper(1) as bus:
        #write a button pin as 8-bit to adress 38, offset 0
        bus.write_byte_data(0x38, 0, btn_pin)
        sleep(DURATION)
        data = 255
        bus.write_byte_data(0x38, 0, data)  
    return JsonResponse()
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name = 'index'),
    path('', views.control_button, name = 'control_button'),
]
```

Many thanks for help.

Comment: You can't have two URL patterns with the same path. The second one would never be called.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. That was indeed a problem. For the record of the others modifying the second path like this: 'control_button/' put the code into work.